# Taking payments through custom facebook page tab iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, e-commerce, payment-gateway, facebook-page

is it within the terms of facebook to allow payments to be taken through a facebook page app?

we have an online store that we have created and styled to fit within a facebook page tab. however our payment gateway does not work whilst being used within an iframe in the facebook environment.

it does work however through an iframe outside of the facebook site.

We are not using paypal, but instead a custom payment gateway.

When i check facebook terms it states that any games must use their facebook payments system however it doesnt mention basic page apps which leads me to believe we can implement our own payment system.

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating with the iframe with javascript, this will
not work when the iframe and the containing page are not from the 
same domain.  That may be why it works locally but not from Facebook.